# Prove this estimator is not sufficient

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I have the following problem. Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample of i.i.d random variables with density $$f_\theta=\begin{cases}
\theta x +\frac{1}{2},&\text{if }-1\le x\le 1\\
0 ,&\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Let $\hat\theta(X)=\frac{3\bar{X}}{2}$ an estimator of $\theta$.

I want to prove that $\hat\theta(X)$ is not sufficient by giving a specific example where $P(X=x|\hat\theta(X)=t)$ depends on $\theta$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the vector of order statistics $T=(X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta$ and $T$ is not a function of $\hat\theta$, we can indirectly say that $\hat\theta$ is not sufficient.